# Stop passing by reference in closures

Tags: javascript, closures, pass-by-reference

I have code that looks like this:

```
var a = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    a[i] = function() {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it seems that `i` is being passed by reference, so all the functions in `a` output 10. How do I make it so that each function outputs the value that `i` had when it was created? I.e. `a[0]()` gives 0, `a[1]()` gives 1, etc.

**EDIT**: to clarify, I do not want `a` to store the values 0-9. I want `a` to store functions that return the values 0-9.

Comment: Classic "closure in a loop" error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to invoke a function (to create a closure that captures your value) which returns a function (the one you want to end up with). Something like this:

```
var a = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    a[i] = (function(value) {
        return function() {
            console.log(value);
        }
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Functionception. I like it!

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. Once you wrap your head around it, the whole closure thing is pretty damn cool.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    a[i] = (function(j) {
        return function () {
            console.log(j);
        }
    })(i);
}
```

A better performing version -

```
function makeFunction(i) {
    return function () {
        console.log(i);
    }
}

var a = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    a[i] = makeFunction(i);
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/p7rxvnmo/1/).

Comment: The first one will not work. It will execute the function immediately, rather than store it in `a` for later execution.

Comment: @Bluefire: I believe now it does what you need. Sorry I did not notice the function storing part.